# JQuery -- load functuion

Tags: jquery

I need to find out how to use a variable instead of a link

Example

```
$("#content").load ("FDT_Guide.aspx #content");
```

The above works however I want to convert it to use a variable instead.

```
 var urllink = FDT_Guide.aspx;
    $("#content").load (""+urllink+"");
```

What am i doing wrong as this is not working?

here is the full code

```
function ShowLinks()
{
countLinks= LinkFilenamearray.length;
countCategory= Categoryarray.length;
for (var i=0; i< countLinks; i++) {
for (var j=0; j< countCategory; j++) {
    if (Categoryarray[j] == LinkCategoryarray[i])
      {
          $("#"+LinkCategoryarray[i]+"Links").append("<a href='#'>" +LinkDisplayarray[i]+"");

          var linkurl = LinkFilenamearray[i];
          //$("#"+LinkCategoryarray[i]+"Links").append("<a href='#'>" +linkurl+"");
                $("#"+LinkCategoryarray[i]+"Links").on("click", "a", function (e) {
                $("#content").load(linkurl + " #content");
                //$("#content").load ("FDT_Guide.aspx #content"); 
                e.preventDefault();
          });


      }
```

the varable LinkFilenamearray[i]; holds stuff like FDT_Guide.aspx
when I output the below code it shows the full link, so i know my array is outputing the correct syntax

```
//$("#"+LinkCategoryarray[i]+"Links").append("<a href='#'>"
```

when i use the below code it works

```
//$("#content").load ("FDT_Guide.aspx #content");
```

I basically need my Array LinkFilenamearray[i] to be used to get the link.
atm when i press a link, nothing happens --

Comment: var urllink = "FDT_Guide.aspx"; $("#content").load (urllink);

Answer (score 2):

You may try this to achieve the equivalent of what you state as a working example:

```
var urllink = "FDT_Guide.aspx";
$("#content").load(urllink + " #content");
```

Comment: you code works until I add my array[i]  var to urllink, when i append urllink it shows the full path name -- very puzzled...  (var urllink = array[i];)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not quite sure what arrays you are talking about. You seem to be showing some `array[i]` variable without actually providing any context or code sample about it. It's pretty hard to be able to help under such circumstances.

Comment: basically I am using sharepoint 365  i have a list with all my URL  links, (eg test.aspx) i am using jquery to get the list urls and I put them into an array, I then show the links on the page using jquery - when the user clicks a link it opens that page in a div  when i output the urllink to the page is shows the full path name each off the list items

Comment: Cool, but what code you have written so far? What difficulties did you encounter with it? What would you like to ask about on StackOverflow?

Comment: Please don't use the comments section to post code snippets as they are completely unreadable. Go ahead and edit your original post if you need to provide additional details and code snippets. Also don't hesitate to ask a real question.

Comment: when i click on the link nothing happens, however if i use $("#content").load ("FDT_Guide.aspx #content");  this works, but need to use a variable as other than the path name

Comment: Well, I am really sorry to hear about that. The code shown in my answer is an absolute equivalent of it. Unfortunately you seem to be using some different code snippet which you seem to be saying that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

worked it out :D

just needed to give the href an id and call the id in the click event

```
function ShowLinks()
{
countLinks= LinkFilenamearray.length;
countCategory= Categoryarray.length;
for (var i=0; i< countLinks; i++) {


for (var j=0; j< countCategory; j++) {
    var linkurl2 = LinkFilenamearray[i];

    if (Categoryarray[j] == LinkCategoryarray[i])
      {
          $("#"+LinkCategoryarray[i]+"Links").append("<a href='#' id="+linkurl2+">" +LinkDisplayarray[i]+"");




                $("#"+LinkCategoryarray[i]+"Links").on("click", "a", function (e) {

                  var linkurl =$(this).attr('id') 

                $("#content").load(linkurl + " #content");
                $("#box").hide(1000);
                $("#WJAbox").hide(1000);
                $("#EWSbox").hide(1000);
                $("#rescodebox").hide(1000);
                $("#PrintServerbox").hide(1000);
                $("#SafecomServerbox").hide(1000);
                $("#HPCRServerbox").hide(1000);
                $("#GPMISServerbox").hide(1000);
                $("#FDTServerbox").hide(1000);
                $("#DCCServerbox").hide(1000);

                e.preventDefault();
          });


      }

}
}
}
```